# Add relationships that has 3 layers, Parent -> Child1 -> Child2

Tags: 8, views, nodes

Recently I asked a question that was similar ([Parent node needs to display the scheduled date that is referenced in the child node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303446/parent-node-needs-to-display-the-scheduled-date-that-is-referenced-in-the-child)), but requirements have changed and now I'm dealing with the Node A (parent) -> Node B (child) -> Node C (grand-child). Bear with me as I explain this.

Node A is the main parent.  It contains an entity reference field that calls Node B.  I've successfully created the contextual filter and relationship to display the necessary information from both Node A and Node B.  Entering the mix is Node C.  Node C contains one piece of info that needs to be displayed.  There is an entity reference field in Node B that calls Node C.

I currently have a contextual filter and relationship on the Node B entity reference field, but the field from Node C isn't displaying.  I'm sure this has to do with there being 3 layers to this view.  Is there something here that I'm missing, or is views unable to handle the 3 layer relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that didn't take much time at all.  After doing a bit more searching around, I came up with the following solution.

Under "Relationships" I created another one on the entity reference field used in Node B.  Then I assigned the relationship that was created for the Node A entity reference field to this new relationship.  Note: the relationship is NOT required because some items do not contain the info from Node C.

Next, under "Fields" I updated the relationship used for the field containing the info from Node C to reference this new relationship. All fields display as/when they should.

I hope this helps someone else out.  Cheers.